Is the initialization of an object a modification to a memory location when considering conflict actions?
struct A{int a; A():a(1){}}
std::atomic<A*> x;

// thread 1:
A* ptr = new A(); // #1
x.store(ptr,memory_order​::​relaxed);

//thread 2:
auto ptr = x.load(memory_order​::​relaxed);
int b = ptr->a;  // #2

intro.races p21 says:

Two actions are potentially concurrent if


they are performed by different threads, or
[...]


The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other,

intro.races p2 defines what two conflict actions are

Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory location ([intro.memory]) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location.

First, the evaluations at #1 and #2 neither happen before the other, and #1 is not atomic, #2 is a read to A::a in the memory pointed to by ptr. However, are they conflict actions? It's unclear.
I don't find wording in the standard that would say the initialization of an object is considered a modification to a memory location. How to interpret this example in terms of C++ standard?

Unless the object fits into a processor's register, it's got to be a modification to memory.

[dcl.init] says that it determines the initial value of the object, but the initial value is determined by [basic.indet]. I think [dcl.init] should be changed to clarify that it modifies the initial value. Also, it might not need to be covered by the definition for conflicting actions because having no happens-before relation with the lifetime of the object beginning (after its initialization) already means that reading ptr->a has undefined behavior.

@ThomasMatthews: This is tagged language-lawyer, so we mean "memory" in the sense of ISO14882, specifically the [intro.memory] section.

In case it's not obvious to anyone, this is purely a [language-lawyer] question about a possible defect in the standard.  It's obviously unsafe in practice to let a read of a variable race with its constructor.  On a machine without dependency ordering in hardware (DEC Alpha, or a hypothetical machine with value-prediction), you could read a stale value.  (Or if the compiler-generated asm for the writer side stored the new pointer before storing to the pointed-to int.  Or runtime reordering of the stores since that store is relaxed not release.)

Can we establish that new first obtains storage and then constructs an object in that location?  When you construct an object in a memory location, any previously existing objects cease to exist.  Maybe something there indicates modification somehow?
